# select code based on cfg attribute not true [rust]

Tags: rust

I want rust code compiled when the compilation attribute `debug_assertions` is false (or not enabled), i.e. a "debug build".
Is this possible? What is the syntax?

For example, I can compile function `build_type` when compiling for debug build (i.e. option `--release` is not passed to command `cargo build`).

```rust
#[cfg(debug_assertions)]
pub fn build_type() -> String {
    String::from("debug")
}
```

In this case, I want a "release version" of the function,

```rust
#[cfg(debug_assertions)]
pub fn build_type() -> String {
    String::from("debug")
}

#[!cfg(debug_assertions)]
pub fn build_type() -> String {
    String::from("release")
}
```

However, the syntax `#[!cfg(debug_assertions)]` results in `cargo build` error `expected identifier, found '!'`.

Other failed syntax variations were:

- `#[cfg(!debug_assertions)]`
- `#[cfg(debug_assertions = false)]`
- `#[cfg(debug_assertions = "false")]`

Answer (score 3):

In book *Rust By Example*, the [section on `cfg`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/attribute/cfg.html) has this snipped code sample:

```rust
// And this function only gets compiled if the target OS is *not* linux
#[cfg(not(target_os = "linux"))]
fn are_you_on_linux() {
    println!("You are *not* running linux!");
}
```

Use syntax `#[cfg(not(debug_assertions))]` to conditionally compile for `cargo build --release`.

The book *The Rust Reference* has the [full list of conditional compilation predicates](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/conditional-compilation.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this, based on [rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/conditional-compilation.html)

```rust
if cfg!(not(target_os = "linux")) {
    // Your code
} else {
    // Your else code
}
```

And to check if it is a debug binary, you can do the same, but with the `debug_assertions` cfg, like this

```rust
if cfg!(debug_assertions) {
    // Your code if is debug
}
```